# Make a call from Samsung 10.1 Android tablet

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I make a call from Samsung 10.1 Android tablet? The tablet supports mini SIM card, 2G and 3G networks. However, I am able to receive SMS on the tablet, but I cannot make any calls. When I want to make a call from within my app, I am redirected to Add a new contact. (Note that it works fine to make a call from a phone device!) Here is my code for making a call:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            String destination = mContactsAt.getText().toString();
            Log.d("CallActivity", "after getting the contact name");

            String phoneNo = getPhoneNumber(destination);               
            Log.d("CallActivity", "after showing number");
            if (phoneNo.startsWith("+")){
                phoneNo.replace("+", "00");                 
            }
            phoneNo.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
            Log.d("CallActivity", "phoneNo to call =" + phoneNo + " destination " + destination);   
            phoneNumber = phoneNo;
            contactName = destination;

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNo.trim()));
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if the tablet has telephony feature enabled.

Comment: Hi, I checked up this tutorial about enabling the telephony feature, but i waited for more feedback if I can do in code. Here is the tutorial if someone needs it: http://androidadvices.com/enable-phone-calling-feature-in-galaxy-tab-10-1-750-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your oncreate():

```
    // Register for Phone Calling
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

and this from where you start the phone call:

```
      Intent callIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_CALL);
      callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:06641234567"));

      startActivity(callIntent);
```

and at least:

```
   public class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

            System.out.println("SPEAKER ON!!");

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

          if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) { // run when
          //class initial and phone call ended, // need detect flag from
          //CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

          if (isPhoneCalling) {

          Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

           //restart app 
           Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
          .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName());
          i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
          startActivity(i);

         isPhoneCalling = false; }

          }

    }
}
```